# Any good recent examples for printing with Java?

Tags: java, printing

I need to know how to setup a class to print from java using the most recent Java Print API.  Everything I find is either obscure or uses outdated APIs.

Comment: Hi Dora, do you have to use java? If not, have a look at xsl:fo, it is really powerful. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects

Comment: I would suggest using PDF as an intermediary and then using iText or similar. I don't know what you actual use case is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples using the Book class at [link text](http://www.datavirtue.com/developers.html)

Comment: I'm currently using iText. Since you can now get free PDF printers I'm looking to eliminate the iText library from my application.  iText is nice but the code to create specific documents is very cumbersome and difficult to maintain.  Then again maybe I need to re-evaluate how I'm using itext.  I actually have iText code available on my website.  http://www.datavirtue.com/developers.html